# Remove selected words from a text file?

Tags: java, parsing, lexical-analysis

I have to remove common words like (is,are,am,was etc) from a text file. what is the efficient way of doing it in java ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to read the file in, skipping the words you want to remove, and then write the file back out again.

Because of this, you may prefer to just skip the words you want to ignore each time you read it - depends on your use case.

To actually remove the words on a line-by-line basis (which may not be the way you want to do it anyway), you could do this (using [google guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)):

```
    // the words you want to remove from the file:
    //
    Set<String> wordsToRemove = ImmutableSet.of("a", "for");

    // this code will run in a loop reading one line after another from the file
    //
    String line = "Some words read from a file for example";
    StringBuffer outputLine = new StringBuffer();
    for (String word : Splitter.on(Pattern.compile("\\s+")).trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(line)) {
        if (!wordsToRemove.contains(word)) {
            if (outputLine.length() > 0) {
                outputLine.append(' ');
            }
            outputLine.append(word);
        }
    }

    // here I'm just printing, but this line could now be written to the output file.
    //
    System.out.println(outputLine.toString());
```

Running this code will output:

```
Some words read from file example
```

I.e, "a" and "for" are omitted.

Notice that this makes for simple code, but, it will change the whitespace formatting in your file.  If you had a line with doubled up spaces, tabs etc, then this all gets changed to a single space in this code.  This is just an example of how you might do it, depending on your requirements, there will probably be better ways.

Comment: Can U please elaborate on it a bit more.!  @daveb

Comment: @SuhailJavid You should be the first one to elaborate. What have you tried so far, what is your code? Do you at least have the code that reads the file?

Comment: @daveb thanks for the help. I have one more issue 'once i omit the words from the string, Is there any way to write the string back in the older format to a new file' ? Please help as I am a beginner !

Comment: @daveb Thanks for replying again..

Writing to the file is ok.. But i am not able to write it back again as per the old format. I mean it should look exactly as the input file, only those words should be omitted. the spaces and paragraphs should be same..!

Comment: Yes, this is the flaw I mentioned in the answer.  In this case, you could read the whole file in, and use String.replace() to replace the words you don't want with a blank string.  However, this would leave one space before the word and one after, so you could search for: some-whitespace followed by the-word (replace with blank) and the-word followed by some-whitespace (replace with blank).  There are more efficient ways than this of course.